# Excel - How to count number of rows in range (i.e. various columns) that contain certain string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have a list A of strings and I want to see if and if yes in how many rows each string is represented in range B. My data looks something like this:

List A:

```
   E
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc
```

Range B:

```
   A      B      C
1 aaa    ---    ---
2 bbb    ccc    bbb
3 aaa    ---    ---
```

My desired result would be that in list A for "aaa" it would tell me 2, for "bbb" 1 and for "ccc" 1. Have been trying to do this with the below array formula but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(Range B,List A($A1)>0,1,0))
```

Comment: @Jeeped I'm pretty sure your edit is wrong. The intention was that Range B spans across multiple columns, not just 1. Please consider rolling back (unfortunately that also renders your answer wrong)

Comment: Oh! I think I finally got your point. You may very well be right.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clarifying, my question was for cases in which Range B spans across multiple columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as I like to avoid encouraging the use of the volatile [OFFSET¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), it seems the most likely candidate in this situation.

[image: COUNTIF across rows]

The *array formula* in F2 is,

```
=SUM(SIGN(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A$2, ROW($1:$99)-1, 0, 1, 3), E2)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula.

¹<sub>[OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) is considered a volatile function that recalculates whenever anything in the workbook changes.</sub>

Comment: Seems like we were thinking along similar lines. I like your use of the `sign` function.

Comment: Yeah, I mucked it up the first time around by misinterpreting the question's sample data but if you give me 99 tries I just might get it right! :P

Answer (score 3):

In the following image

[image]

`B` is the name for the range `A1:C4`. In F1 (next to the first element in your list `A`), enter:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B,ROW(B)-1,0,1),E1)>0,1,0)
```

(entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter) and copy down.

It should be flexible enough to handle a `B` which grows to more rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

There have already been some great answers posted here, but I thought I would add one more. If you are working with a large data set, this formula could come in handy in terms of speed. You can place the formula in F1 (See image below) and copy down. You will need to use **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** when entering the formula.

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(E1=$A$1:$C$3,ROW($A$1:$C$3)),IF(E1=$A$1:$C$3,ROW($A$1:$C$3)))>0,1))
```

[image]